# Pass arguments from file to a script run from dockerfile

Tags: bash, ubuntu, dockerfile

In my `Dockerfile` I want to run a command that executes a bash script which gets passed arguments that are read from a file.

In `plugins.txt` is a plugin specified (full file content: `configuration-as-code`), but the bash script does not receive any argument at all.

But as I've found this way how to install plugins on a [blog post](https://liquidstate.net/jenkins-setup/), I assume it should work as-is.

```
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
COPY install-plugins.sh /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
```

The installer script starts with following lines and exits with `Usage /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh plugin1 plugin 2 ...`

```
#!/bin/bash 

set -e

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "USAGE: $0 plugin1 plugin2 ..."
  exit 1
fi
```

How can I correctly pass the contents of file `plugins.txt` to the script?

EDIT

I've found a solution that passes the arguments correctly. Does someone know why the initial attempt is wrong?

It works with:

```
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh $(cat /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I/O redirection is not a parameter of a script.

We can use `tty` command to check if the script is using I/O redirection to read from a file.

If the script has a TTY then check the number of parameters. Read plugin names from parameters.

If it doesn't have a TTY, it means we use I/O redirection, we don't need to check parameters in this case. Read plugin names from I/O redirection into an array variable `plugins` by `mapfile` command.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

if tty &>/dev/null && [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "USAGE: $0 plugin1 plugin2 ..."
  exit 1
fi

if tty &>/dev/null; then
  plugins=("$@")
else
  mapfile -t plugins
fi

for plugin in "${plugins[@]}"; do
  echo install_plugin "$plugin"
done
```